# Clean up SQL query with nested tables

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT l.userid
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT userid, CAST(tmstmp AS DATE)
        FROM logins
        WHERE type <> 'mobile'
        AND tmstmp BETWEEN '2013-04-21' AND '2014-04-21') l
    GROUP BY l.userid
    HAVING count(*) > 5) t;
```

Hello, Can I please have suggestions on how I can clean up this query... maybe a clever way to remove one of the nested tables? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is this query supposed to do? Count the number of users who logged in more than 5 times between the given dates?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Just couldn't seem to make it look nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for an `aggregate` within another `aggregate`.  I think this is your best option using a single subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT userid
    FROM logins
    WHERE type <> 'mobile' AND tmstmp BETWEEN '2013-04-21' AND '2014-04-21'
    GROUP BY userid
    HAVING count(distinct CAST(tmstmp AS DATE)) > 5
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Using WITH will make it more readable:

```
WITH matching_users AS (
  SELECT userid
  FROM logins
  WHERE type <> 'mobile' AND tmstmp BETWEEN '2013-04-21' AND '2014-04-21'
  GROUP BY userid
  HAVING count(distinct CAST(tmstmp AS DATE)) > 5
)
SELECT count(*) FROM matching_users
```

Comment: Unfortunately `mysql` doesn't support `common table expressions`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
SELECT userid, COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(tmstmp AS DATE)) as number_of_logins
FROM logins l
WHERE type <> 'mobile' AND tmstmp BETWEEN '2013-04-21' AND '2014-04-21'
GROUP BY l.userid
HAVING number_of_logins > 5) t
```

This gets the distinct number of dates for logins and counts only those users with more than 5